# Verwendung von »stromern«

Tags: regional, verb-usage

In der Zeit vom 20. August war ein großer Artikel über Kinder und ihr freies Spiel, der an mehreren Stellen das Verb »herumstromern« benutzt hat. Mein erster Gedanke war »das hat der Autor doch erfunden«, allerdings überzeugt mich die Recherche auf [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/stromern), [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/stromern:V:haben:sein) und [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/stromern) vom Gegenteil. Ich bin auch froh, dass ich die Bedeutung aus dem Kontext richtig erschlossen habe; es bedeutet »herumstreunern, sich herumtreiben«.

Eine kurze Umfrage unter Freunden scheint mich in meiner Ansicht zu bestätigen, dass der Ausdruck in meiner *Peer-Group* wenig bekannt ist, und in meiner Region selten verwendet wird.

- Gibt es Regionen im deutschsprachigen Raum, in der er häufig verwendet wird?
- Oder ist das Verb veraltet, gehoben, oder sonstwie seltener in Verwendung?

Comment: Hab ich in meiner Kindheit oft gehört. Ich glaube vor allem von meiner Oma (schlesische Vertriebene) und meiner Tante in Halle/Saale.

Comment: Ich vermute mal, dass das Wort in Norddeutschland allgemein bekannt ist (wird aber relativ selten verwendet). Gefühlt ist es für mich ein aus Hamburg stammendes Wort (da kann ich mich aber auch komplett irren).

Comment: Ich kenne die Bezeichnung _Stromer_ für einen streunenden Hund.

Comment: @hellcode würde zur Zeit passen ;)

Comment: Die Autorin (Katrin Hörnlein) scheint aus dem Raum Köln zu stammen.

Comment: Nur für mich selbst aus Berlin: Mir ist das Wort bekannt, es ist nicht gehoben, meine Eltern würden es eher verwenden als ich, es ist (nun) selten genug, dass ich leicht zögern würde, es zu schreiben, weil ich mir nicht sicher wäre, ob ich es richtig verwende.

Comment: Was ist denn Deine Region? Mir ist das Wort geläufig, aber heute stromert man kaum noch rum. Das passt eher zu Bewegungsformen in Wald und Flur, weniger zu Städten und Wegen.

Comment: @userunknown Oberbayern-West, aber ich hab auch im Allgäu gefragt. (Der Artikel hat ja ausdrücklich das herumstromern in der Natur, Wald und Wiese, nahegelegt.)

Comment: @Jan: Wo hat er das nahegelegt? Herumstreunen passt m.E. auch gut für das Stadtviertel. Jedenfalls können Wörter selten werden, weil sie durch andere ersetzt werden oder weil sie einen Tatbestand beschreiben, der selten geworden ist - letzteres wollte ich nahelegen.

Comment: @userunknown Im Wortlaut. Ich könnte jetzt aufstehen und den Artikel zum zitieren holen gehen, aber ich bin zu faul. Herumstromern kommt in 90 % der Fälle direkt mit »in der Natur«, »im Wald«, »in der Düne« oder ähnlichem vor. Nur dadurch hab ich mir die Bedeutung auch im Kontext erschließen können ;)

Comment: @Jan: Ach, der Artikel, in dem Du dem Wort begegnet bist. Ich dachte, in dem Artikel, den Du hier geschrieben hast. Da kann ich ja lange suchen! :)

Comment: @userunknown, Großstadtdschungel!

Comment: Ich halte "herumstromern" für norddeutsch. Im Süden eigentlich ungebräuchlich.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Das *Variantenwörterbuch des Deutschen* stuft *stromern* als (nur) in ganz Deutschland verbreitet ein, wobei es im Südosten in Konkurrenz zu *strawanzen* steht, das auch in Österreich verbreitet ist. In der Schweiz soll *stromern* „selten“ auch vorkommen..

Comment: In Österreich wird strawanzen nie alleine stehend verwendet sondern immer im Zusammenhang mit einer Richtungsangabe -> ***'herum strawanzen'*** oder ***'durch die Gegend strawanzen'*** - Als Hauptwort ***'Strawanzer'*** geht es auch ohne - neben ***'Herumstrawanzer'***...

Comment: Ich kenne und nutze auch nur  _herum/rumstromern_. _Stromern_ allein hört sich seltsam an.

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde aus der Erinnerung sagen, in den siebziger Jahren im Ruhrgebiet hätte es wohl jeder auf Anhieb verstanden.

Bekanntlich ist das Ruhrgebiet sowohl durch die Arbeiterklasse in Zeche und Stahlwerk als auch durch Zuwanderung aus den Gebieten der Oder und jenseits davon geprägt. Um da den entscheidenden Einfluss einschätzen zu können, bin ich allerdings selbst zu jung. :-)

Etwas geläufiger scheint mir *Stromer*, welches der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Stromer) als abwertend und Jargon für Landstreicher anführt. (Auch das [Verb](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/stromern) kennt er übrigens.) Allerdings kenne ich es eher als Übertreibung für «Herumtreiber/herumtreiben» gegenüber Kindern oder Haustieren, was dem Duden ja auch nicht widerspricht.

Answer (score 0):

Vielleicht bedingt durch den Umstand, dass man es heutzutage selten hört (vgl. den Kommentar von Carsten S., der wortgleich auch von mir stammen könnte), fehlt für mich beim *herumstromern* die negative Konnotation, die das ansonsten bedeutungsgleiche *herumstreunen* hat.
Der *Stromer* als Substantiv ist mir nicht geläufig, und *stromern* ohne ein *herum* davor kommt mir zumindest ungewöhnlich vor.